# CUDA 2D ARRAY - Working with elements

Tags: arrays, cuda, 2d

I am learning cuda and managed to get a 2D Array in there, and return a 2D array of doubles, with some minor issues. Now, I want , for example, to set all values to 250 of double all values, but I cant seem to get past the first row. I can't get to seem to loop correctly. I am doubting if it is the number of blocks/threads or the code itself . Here is my complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std; 

#define THETA 10

// Error checking.
//
#define gpuErrorCheck(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}


// Pass 2-dim array to GPU and change it there.
//
__global__ 
void addArrays(double *twoDimArray, size_t pitch) 
{
    printf("\n\nOn GPU array : thread : %d\n", threadIdx.x);

    int tidx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;  //// tidx = Columns in CUDA
    int tidy = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;  //// tidy = Rows In cuda

    if ((tidx < THETA) && (tidy < THETA))
    {
    double tempval = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < THETA ; i++)
        {
            tempval = 250; 
        }
    twoDimArray[tidy * THETA + tidx]=tempval;
    }


}

int main() 
{

    //
    // 2-Dimensional Array
    //

    printf("\n*******************\n2-DIMENSIONAL ARRAY\n*******************\n\n");

    // Create 2-dim array on the CPU.
    //
    double arrayOnCpu[THETA][THETA];
    double arrayOnCpu2[THETA][THETA];     

    // Initialise the vector of vector on the CPU.
    //
    for (int i = 0; i < THETA; i++) // Aantal buitenste vectoren.
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < THETA; j++) // Aantal binnenste elementen.
        {
            arrayOnCpu2[i][j] = j;
        }   
    }

    // Print the vector of vectors.
    //
    for (int i = 0; i < THETA; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < THETA; j++)
        {
            printf("%2.2f\t", arrayOnCpu2[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n"); 
    }

    // Create corresponding double array on the GPU.
    //
    double *pToArrayOnGpu;
    size_t pitch;

    gpuErrorCheck( cudaMallocPitch((void **)&pToArrayOnGpu, &pitch, THETA * sizeof(double), THETA) );

    // Copy CPU data to vector on GPU.
    //
    gpuErrorCheck( cudaMemcpy2D(pToArrayOnGpu, pitch, arrayOnCpu2, pitch, THETA * sizeof(double), THETA, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

    // Launch GPU code with THETA threads, one per vector element.
    //
    addArrays<<<1, THETA>>>(pToArrayOnGpu, pitch);
    gpuErrorCheck( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );


    // Copy array from GPU back to CPU.
    //
    gpuErrorCheck( cudaMemcpy2D(arrayOnCpu2, pitch, pToArrayOnGpu,pitch, THETA * sizeof(double), THETA,  cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );

    // Print the vector of vectors.
    //
    for (int i = 0; i < THETA; i++) // Aantal buitenste vectoren.
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < THETA; j++) // Aantal binnenste elementen.
        {
            printf("%2.2f\t", arrayOnCpu2[i][j]);
        }  
        printf("\n"); 
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    // Free up the array on the GPU.
    //
    gpuErrorCheck( cudaFree(pToArrayOnGpu) );



    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with the code is that you confused the `pitch` concept of 2D arrays on the host side and the device side. Below is a brief introduction.

In host, a[row][column] stored in `a+row*width_of_column*sizeof(element)+column*sizeof(element)`. But in cuda's global memory access, continuous access from 256-byte aligned addresses (addr=0, 256, 512, ...) is the most efficient. Thus, in order to improve the efficiency of memory access, the cudaMallocPitch function is available.

In the memory allocated by the cudaMallocPitch(), address of the first element of each row of the array is aligned. Since data per line is undefined,  `row*width_of_column*sizeof(element)` is not necessarily a multiple of 256. Therefore, in order to ensure the start address alignment of the first element of each line of the array, `cudaMallocPitch()` allocates more bytes per line when allocating memory to ensure that `width_of_column*sizeof(element)+extra allocated bytes` are
Multiples of 256 (aligned). Also,the `pitch` returned from `cudaMallocPitch()` Should add extra allocated memory.
The function prototype is as follow:

```
__host__ ​cudaError_t cudaMemcpy2D ( void* dst, size_t dpitch, const void* src, size_t spitch, size_t width, size_t height, cudaMemcpyKind kind )
```

So, When you use cudaMemcpy2D(), You should give the correct `pitch` which means the pitch is not the same in the array of hosts and devices. In your case,it should be like:

```
gpuErrorCheck(cudaMemcpy2D(pToArrayOnGpu, pitch, arrayOnCpu2, THETA * sizeof(double), THETA * sizeof(double), THETA, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
```

The first pitch(dpitch) is returned from `cudaMallocPitch()`while the last one(spitch) is `THETA * sizeof(double)`.
You can get more info in this [link](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g3a58270f6775efe56c65ac47843e7cee).

I made a brief change to your code, which can run correctly on my machine.

```
env: Ubuntu 16.04 Tesla P100

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#define THETA 10
// Error checking.
#define gpuErrorCheck(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort = true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

// Pass 2-dim array to GPU and change it there.
//
__global__
void addArrays(double *twoDimArray, size_t pitch){
    int tidx = threadIdx.x;
    if ((tidx < THETA) /*&& (tidy < THETA)*/){
        double tempval = 250;
        for (int i = 0; i < THETA; i++){
            double* row = (double*)((char*)twoDimArray + i * pitch);
            row[tidx] *= tempval;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    double arrayOnCpu2[THETA][THETA];

    // Initialise the vector of vector on the CPU.
    for (int i = 0; i < THETA; i++){ // Aantal buitenste vectoren.
        for (int j = 0; j < THETA; j++) // Aantal binnenste elementen.
            arrayOnCpu2[i][j] = j;
    }
    // Print the vector of vectors.
    printf("Before:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < THETA; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < THETA; j++)
            printf("%2.2f\t", arrayOnCpu2[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    // Create corresponding double array on the GPU.
    double *pToArrayOnGpu;
    size_t pitch;
    gpuErrorCheck(cudaMallocPitch((void **)&pToArrayOnGpu, &pitch, THETA * sizeof(double), THETA));

    // Copy CPU data to vector on GPU.
    gpuErrorCheck(cudaMemcpy2D(pToArrayOnGpu, pitch, arrayOnCpu2, THETA * sizeof(double), THETA * sizeof(double), THETA, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // Launch GPU code with THETA threads, one per vector element.
    addArrays << <1, THETA >> >(pToArrayOnGpu, pitch);
    gpuErrorCheck(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    // Copy array from GPU back to CPU.
    gpuErrorCheck(cudaMemcpy2D(arrayOnCpu2, THETA * sizeof(double), pToArrayOnGpu, pitch, THETA * sizeof(double), THETA, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    // Print the vector of vectors.
    printf("After:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < THETA; i++){ // Aantal buitenste vectoren.
        for (int j = 0; j < THETA; j++) // Aantal binnenste elementen.
            printf("%2.2f\t", arrayOnCpu2[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    // Free up the array on the GPU.
    gpuErrorCheck(cudaFree(pToArrayOnGpu));
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Before:
0.00    1.00    2.00    3.00    4.00    5.00    6.00    7.00    8.00    9.00    
0.00    1.00    2.00    3.00    4.00    5.00    6.00    7.00    8.00    9.00    
0.00    1.00    2.00    3.00    4.00    5.00    6.00    7.00    8.00    9.00    
0.00    1.00    2.00    3.00    4.00    5.00    6.00    7.00    8.00    9.00    
0.00    1.00    2.00    3.00    4.00    5.00    6.00    7.00    8.00    9.00    
0.00    1.00    2.00    3.00    4.00    5.00    6.00    7.00    8.00    9.00    
0.00    1.00    2.00    3.00    4.00    5.00    6.00    7.00    8.00    9.00    
0.00    1.00    2.00    3.00    4.00    5.00    6.00    7.00    8.00    9.00    
0.00    1.00    2.00    3.00    4.00    5.00    6.00    7.00    8.00    9.00    
0.00    1.00    2.00    3.00    4.00    5.00    6.00    7.00    8.00    9.00    
After:
0.00    250.00  500.00  750.00  1000.00 1250.00 1500.00 1750.00 2000.00 2250.00 
0.00    250.00  500.00  750.00  1000.00 1250.00 1500.00 1750.00 2000.00 2250.00 
0.00    250.00  500.00  750.00  1000.00 1250.00 1500.00 1750.00 2000.00 2250.00 
0.00    250.00  500.00  750.00  1000.00 1250.00 1500.00 1750.00 2000.00 2250.00 
0.00    250.00  500.00  750.00  1000.00 1250.00 1500.00 1750.00 2000.00 2250.00 
0.00    250.00  500.00  750.00  1000.00 1250.00 1500.00 1750.00 2000.00 2250.00 
0.00    250.00  500.00  750.00  1000.00 1250.00 1500.00 1750.00 2000.00 2250.00 
0.00    250.00  500.00  750.00  1000.00 1250.00 1500.00 1750.00 2000.00 2250.00 
0.00    250.00  500.00  750.00  1000.00 1250.00 1500.00 1750.00 2000.00 2250.00 
0.00    250.00  500.00  750.00  1000.00 1250.00 1500.00 1750.00 2000.00 2250.00
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was a solution for me

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you generally want to avoid using `double` on the GPU if you can. While basically all CUDA-capable consumer GPUs nowadays do support double precision arithmetic in some way, it's usually much much slower than single precision.

Apart from that, there seems to be some confusion concerning what the different pitches are supposed to mean. In general, the pitch of an array is the number of bytes you have to skip from the beginning of one row to get to the beginning of the next row. The driver may choose/need to add padding between the rows of a 2D array to make the allocation meet alignment requirements of the hardware and/or allow for more optimal memory access. That means, for a 2D array on the GPU, the pitch may be larger than just `element size * width`.

For your CPU array, however, the pitch, is just `THETA * sizeof(double)`. The pitch of your GPU array is returned to you from `cudaMallocPitch()`. In your call to `cudaMemcpy2D()`, you pass the pitch of the GPU array as both, the GPU and the CPU pitch. Use the correct pitch for your CPU array. In your device code, you access the GPU array via `twoDimArray[tidy * THETA + tidx]`. Here, you're effectively using a pitch of `THETA * sizeof(double)` to access the GPU data. You should have used the actual pitch of the array instead. For example:

```
double* my_row = reinterpret_cast<double*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(twoDimArray) + tidy * pitch);
my_row[tidx] = tempval;
```